# How to deal with subquery returning more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my case I have 2 tables Project and Activity and they look like this.

[image: Tables]

Project is the table at the top and Activity at the bottom.

In the Activity table activityID and projectID are Primary Keys.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a View that returns All projects that have Activities that have endDate later than the Project projectedEndDate.

In summary I want to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Project
WHERE (SELECT MAX(endDate) FROM Activity GROUP BY projectID) > projectedEndDate
```

But I get the following error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Thank you

Comment: Add a `LIMIT 1` to it?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Since subquery is grouped on project ID, `limit 1` is not what OP needs, because he may get dates from a wrong project.

Comment: Also, `LIMIT 1` is **not** standard SQL. It only works on MySql, and this question is tagged Sql Server.

Comment: And it's considered very rude here to post an image of your sample data instead of text.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't think 'very rude' is appropriate as I think I haven't offended anyone. Will keep in mind next time I post though. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `GROUP BY` returns one row per project ID.

You need to restructure your query to use join:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Project p
JOIN (
    SELECT projectID, MAX(endDate) as maxEnd
    FROM Activity
    GROUP BY projectID
) a ON a.projectID = p.projectID
WHERE a.maxEnd > projectedEndDate
```

This will produce all projects that have an activity ending past the end date of the project.

Comment: @toonice I modified the answer to exclude fields from subquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you want with a slight tweak to your query.  You just need a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Project p
WHERE (SELECT MAX(a.endDate)
       FROM Activity a
       WHERE a.projectId = p.projectId
      ) > p.projectedEndDate
```

In other words, instead of `GROUP BY`, you need a correlation clause.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure JOIN version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM Project p
JOIN Activity a on a.projectID = p.projectID
AND a.endDate > p.projectedEndDate
```

IMHO it's quite neat and tidy.